# Multiple section with one array in tableview iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview

i am newbie in iOS development. my array contain 50 values i want to show this 50 values in one by one in 50 section then i write a code for that like as

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
return self.dataArray.count;
 }
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 1;
}
```

then i got 50 section but all section contain same array value i want to show that each section contain one by one data.Please give me any solution if it was possible

My TablwviewCell:Rowatindexpath method

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellidentifier=@"Cell";
CustumCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustumCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell=[nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

NSDictionary *dict = [self.imagesa objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
NSString *img2=[dict valueForKey:@"post_image"];

[cell.photoimage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[img2 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Hisoka.jpg"] options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"downloaded");

    });
}];
NSString *name=[dict valueForKey:@"post_title"];
cell.namelabel.text=name;
NSString *des=[dict valueForKey:@"post_content"];
cell.deslabel.text=des;


NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
 NSString *date=[dict valueForKey:@"post_date"];
NSDate * dateNotFormatted = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d-MMM-YYYY"];
NSString * dateFormatted = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateNotFormatted];
NSLog(@"Date %@",dateFormatted);
cell.datelabel.text=dateFormatted;
return cell;
}
```

Comment: Could you post your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method?

Comment: yes i post my tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: One issue is that when i run this application and do nothing but after 2 to 3 minutes error in line NSDictionary *dict = [self.imagesa objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]; any solution for that????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think logically through this, the `indexPath.row` will always be 0 since each `section` has one row. Hence, the row number you are using on the array will grab the same item **every** time.

The only value that's increasing each time is the `indexPath.section`. If you use this value while iterating through the array it will lead to the different values in the corresponding array.

Answer (score 1):

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method (and the other datasource/delegate methods, use `indexPath.section` as the index to your data array, not `indexPath.row`.

Or in your case, replace

```
NSDictionary *dict = [self.imagesa objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
```

with

```
NSDictionary *dict = [self.imagesa objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
```

Answer (score 0):

use `indexpath.section`instead of`indexpath.row`in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.